# Deadlock - all goroutines are asleep (even when using wait groups)

Tags: go, goroutine, waitgroup

I am learning go concurrency and I want two go routines to keep talking to each other while passing along updated values via channels. One add 2 to the number while the other subtracts 1. The code and the output are given below:

What's wrong with this code?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func addTwo(r chan int, e chan int) {
    val := <-r
    fmt.Println("AT Recieved: ", val)
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    e <- val + 2
}

func subtractOne(r chan int, e chan int) {
    val := <-r
    fmt.Println("SO Recieved: ", val)
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    e <- val - 1
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    ch2 := make(chan int)

    wg.Add(1)
    go addTwo(ch, ch2)

    wg.Add(1)
    go subtractOne(ch2, ch)

    ch <- 1
    wg.Wait()

}
```

Output:

```
AT Recieved:  1
SO Recieved:  3
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [semacquire]:
sync.runtime_Semacquire(0x4b2de8?)
    /usr/lib/go-1.18/src/runtime/sema.go:56 +0x25
sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait(0x0?)
    /usr/lib/go-1.18/src/sync/waitgroup.go:136 +0x52
main.main()
```

And then it just exits.

Why aren't the goroutines exchanging values forever, even when I am not calling wg.Done() in the goroutines?

Comment: But they are writing to receive it from different channels, and also, I am sending a value on the first channel. See the output, it prints the first couple of exchange values. Also, adding `defer wg.Done()` doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your launched goroutines just receive one value and send one, then they end. From there on there's only the `main` goroutine, blocked at `wg.Wait()` since you never call `wg.Done()`.

You forgot to use a(n endless) loop:

```
func addTwo(r chan int, e chan int) {
    for {
        val := <-r
        fmt.Println("AT Recieved: ", val)
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        e <- val + 2
    }
}

func subtractOne(r chan int, e chan int) {
    for {
        val := <-r
        fmt.Println("SO Recieved: ", val)
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        e <- val - 1
    }
}
```

With this change your app goes on forever, output being:

```
AT Recieved:  1
SO Recieved:  3
AT Recieved:  2
SO Recieved:  4
AT Recieved:  3
SO Recieved:  5
AT Recieved:  4
....
```